# Java can't upload file with @Pathvariable optional

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

I try to build a todoapp with the function to upload files. Now i want to can upload files on a task or simply upload files without tasks. For that i need the @PathVariable Annotation to be optional.

This is my Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/upload/{taskId}")
private ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@CurrentUser UserPrincipal userPrincipal, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] file, @PathVariable(required = false) String taskId) {
    fileService.upload(userPrincipal.getUser(), file, taskId);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("File uploaded", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

If i try it to upload with a TaskId it works. But when i try it to upload without a taskId it doesnt work. I got the error:

"405  Method not allowed"

Screenshot:
[image]

Does somebody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the  `@PathVariable` as an optional be sure to bind both paths: `@PostMapping(value = {"/upload/{taskId}", "/upload"})`.

If you don't post the `taskId` spring will look for a controller that handles `"/upload"` instead of `"/upload/{taskId}"`

Personally i would use `RequestParam` instead of `PathVariable` for optional parameters